# Trying to program a 2D Unity code that shows if my character is grounded or not and it's not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

How can I make the ground so that the character recognize that it is ground? I'm trying to do a 2D jump movement. It's either the `Collisions2D` couldn't find `GetComponent` or the game works but the character doesn't jump at all.

**Error:**

> error CS1061: 'Collision2D' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetComponent' and no accessible extension method 'GetComponent'
> accepting a first argument of type 'Collision2D' could be found

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grounded : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Player;

    void Start()
    {
        Player = GetComponentInParent<GameObject>();
    }

    void Update(){
    }
    
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    
        if (col.GetComponent<Collider2D>().tag == "Ground") {
        
            Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = true;
            
        }
    }
    
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col) {
    
        if (col.GetComponent<Collider2D>().tag == "Ground") {
        
            Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = false;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `col.collider.tag == "Ground"` instead.

`col.collider` refers to the incomming collider, in your case ground. Because that's the collider that you're colliding with (only when you touch the ground of course).

`col.otherCollider` can be used to call the other collider, in your case the player itself. This can be useful when have a lot of collisions.

Feel free to ask for more help is this wasn't enough.